# hamachi home server running apache2 - will be accessible from other networks?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, hamachi

I've an interesting problem. I cannot SSH into my home server from outside my internet providers network (fastweb.it). I tried to setup dynamic DNS, but it just didn't work out, I learned my provider is a pain.

I was thinking, maybe I could use hamachi - set it up on my Linux box, this way I will have IP address accessible from outside provider network.

But I've limited knowledge of how this neat program works, so will I be able to access my Apache2 with hamachi IP from any computer in the world? (I've a feeling I will need to install hamachi on all computers from where I want to access the server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do you bind ssh to all IP? `netstat -na | grep :22`
2. If you'll create Hamachi-tunnel over additional hamachi-interface (and ssh listening on it), when yes - you'll be able to ssh on your hamachi-ip

Comment: 1. Yes.
2. That's a bit too hard for me... can explain in detail please? what do you mean by additional hamachi-interface?

Comment: Well, I can't add screenshots into answer, thus - will answer in  text-only mode. After installing Hamachi you'll see new added network interface in Network Connections, which Hamachi will use on work. [See also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi_(software)#Addressing)